# How do I align the cursor in the firefox search bar back to the left?

Tags: firefox

so my cats walked all over my computer and next thing I know, I go to type something in the search bar and it's aligned to the right rather than the left. I don't know what they did or how I can fix it! I have a macOS mojave version 10.14.6, and the browser is Firefox, if that means anything. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like your cats have pressed shift with a cut shortcut. Hit Shift+Ctrl+X to fix the alignment of cursor to back again to the left. For MacOS hit Shift+⌘+X and the ⌘ like key in your mac keyboard is also called the Command key, which is Ctrl in windows keyboard.

Comment: It worked! Thank you!

Comment: Welcome! Please check mark the big tick mark above the answer

Comment: For MacOS, it's CMD+Shift+X